# How I can hide the jQuery Validate error container when there are no errors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to hide my wrapper that hold errors when the form have no errors. do someone know how to apply this in my code.

Actually when form is correctly fill.  I have seen "Please fill these things". Do someone know how to hide them when their is no errors.

```
$("#contactForm").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#contactAlert ul"),
    errorElement: 'li',
    rules: {

    },
    messages: {
      },
    highlight: function (error, element) {
        $("#contactAlert").removeClass('hide');
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        this.labelContainer.append(error);
    }
});
// call valid to see errors
var valid = $("#contactForm").valid();

console.log(valid);
```

Comment: Sorry, but jQuery don't provide a "validate method". Are you using a jQuery plug-in? And if yes, what's it?

Comment: @Plap, based on the code format, I can tell he's using the jQuery Validate plugin, although the OP never said so.

Comment: Your code, [as you've posted it](http://jsfiddle.net/X2DCU/), is already showing & hiding the error messages and container.  You'll have to better explain what you're trying to do here.  http://jsfiddle.net/X2DCU/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your code, as you've posted it, is already showing & hiding the error messages and container](http://jsfiddle.net/X2DCU/).  You'll have to better explain what you're trying to achieve here.

---

You never explained why you're using `highlight` and `errorPlacement` in your code.  Based on your OP alone, there's no reason to over-ride these two callback functions.

By default, the plugin already does what you want... the errors are automatically shown & hidden.  And in the demo, I colored your wrapper to show that's it's not displayed when the errors are gone.

**Working Demo (with your container):  http://jsfiddle.net/eVax5/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contactForm").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $("#contactAlert ul"),
        errorElement: 'li',
        rules: {
            // rules
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="contactForm">
    ...
</form>

<div id="contactAlert">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

---

**And a "default" example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y6HTz/**

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contactForm").validate({
        // other options,
        rules: {
            // rules
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="contactForm">
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically when you resubmit the form, before checking the form you should simply hide the error message.

Answer (score -1):

while entering your values it should check validation means store your validate function in local variable and recheck again.. sure it should work